# Iterator and linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, listiterator

I'm making a college project in which **I can't use Java API**, so I need to create my own linked list.

Besides, other requirement is use a iterator with the list.

What is exactly a iterator? Why is important to use a iterator with a linked list?

I will use the iterator to all actions in my list, like add a link and etc?

Comment: [See how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's a standard implementation of the [Iterator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

An iterator simply lets one <strike>delete whole  living creatures</strike> iterate through classes implementing List (LinkedList included)

[MORE INFO](http://bfy.tw/30jl)